# Problem opening Catfish: 'get_geometry'?

Tags: nvidia, package-management, python, search

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04. I've been using the Catfish search tool successfully for a while on 20.04 but since I updated to 21.04 it fails to open. (I've tried reinstalling it a few times, no different). When I open it from the terminal this is what I get:

```
john@john-u:~$ catfish
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/catfish", line 44, in <module>
    catfish.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catfish/__init__.py", line 78, in main
    window = CatfishWindow.CatfishWindow()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catfish_lib/Window.py", line 176, in __new__
    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catfish/CatfishWindow.py", line 327, in finish_initializing
    (screen_width, screen_height) = self.get_screen_size()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catfish/CatfishWindow.py", line 405, in get_screen_size
    geometry = monitor.get_geometry()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_geometry'
```

It seems to be something related to display configuration? Could it be related to the fact I am running multiple (3) monitors? I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GB GDDR5 video card and am using X.Org X server.

Thanks in advance for any help!
JohnS

Comment: It's a bug. Apparently an exception can occur on "monitor", being None. get_geometry obviously can't handle that. The  code should be edited to decide what happens when the exception occurs, or fix it to happen anyway. Best to file a bug.